# Select clients that that don't have an event after a certain date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I have two tables involved in this situation:

`tools_events`

| COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| event_id | int |
| event_type | varchar |
| event_value | varchar |
| event_client | int |
| event_timestamp | datetime |

`tools_clients`

| COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| client_id | int |
| client_name | varchar |
| client_developer | int |

This is using MySQL 5.6.

The events table obviously stores events that are occurring throughout a day, and clients contains a list of clients.

There is a particular event I am looking for the **lack of**. For this particular event the `event_type` would be `taskUpdated` and `event_code` would be `needs approval (dev)`.

Currently I have a statement put together that will pull all clients that **have gotten** an event logged after the specified date which seems to be working well, albeit extremely slow:

```
SELECT 
    t1.event_id, t1.event_user, t1.event_client, t1.event_timestamp
FROM 
    tools_events AS t1 
WHERE 
    t1.event_id = (SELECT t2.event_id 
                   FROM tools_events AS t2 
                   WHERE t2.event_type = 'taskUpdated' 
                     AND t2.event_value = 'needs approval (dev)' 
                     AND t2.event_client = t1.event_client 
                     AND t2.event_timestamp >= '2022-04-04 00:00:00' 
                   ORDER BY t2.event_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)
```

What I'm looking for is a way to `client_id`, `client_name`, and `client_developer` from `tools_clients` for the clients who have not had this event logged past the specified date. Short of pulling this list into PHP and cross referencing a full list of the clients to see which ones aren't there, I am unsure of how to tackle this in a SQL query.

On the other end, it seems that just getting a list of events that match the initial criteria seems to run pretty much instantly so perhaps it would be more efficient to just pull those and do all of the logic in PHP? My understanding as I am learning more in depth SQL is that oftentimes SQL is more efficient if you can optimize the query correctly which I don't think I am.

Here is some sample data for the `tools_clients` table:

| client_id | client_name | client_developer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | 12 |
| 2 | fooBar | 15 |
| 3 | Bar | 21 |
| 4 | raBoof | 37 |

And here is some sample data for the `tools_events` table:

| event_id | event_type | event_value | event_client | event_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | taskUpdated | needs approval (dev) | 1 | 2022-04-02 13:08:22 |
| 25 | taskUpdated | needs approval (dev) | 2 | 2022-04-02 14:22:07 |
| 28 | taskUpdated | needs approval (dev) | 3 | 2022-04-02 15:09:13 |
| 29 | taskUpdated | needs approval (dev) | 4 | 2022-04-02 15:36:17 |
| 32 | taskUpdated | needs approval (dev) | 3 | 2022-04-05 16:42:35 |
| 38 | taskUpdated | needs approval (dev) | 4 | 2022-04-05 19:01:25 |

Given the constraints:

```
WHERE event_type = 'taskUpdated' 
  AND event_value = 'needs approval (dev)' 
  AND event_timestamp >= '2022-04-04 00:00:00'
```

I would be looking for the following result because these are the only two that did not have a matching event occurring after the specified date:

| client_id | client_name | client_developer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | 12 |
| 2 | fooBar | 15 |

Any assistance in this even if it's a point in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**

With the simplified version of my original query, provided by Paul Maxwell in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71792719/1163705), as a subquery and a bit more Googling I think I was able to get something working. My understanding is that subqueries are less efficient than JOINs so I'm not sure if this is a solid solution or not but it seems to be running well:

```
SELECT client_id, client_name, client_developer
FROM `tools_clients` AS clients
WHERE client_status > 0
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT event_client
                  FROM tools_events AS events
                  WHERE event_type = 'taskUpdated'
                    AND event_value = 'needs approval (dev)'
                    AND event_timestamp >= '2022-04-04 00:00:00'
                    AND clients.client_id = events.event_client
                  GROUP BY event_client)
```

Side note: I know `client_status` is not mentioned in the original question. At the moment I wasn't worried about that part as I knew I could easily add in that condition once I got something that was otherwise working.

Comment: A) Could you post some sample rows from those tables? Just enough rows to demonstrate the issue.  Also, you don't have to include all of the columns - just the ones referenced in your query above B) Using the sample data, post the expected results C) Which dbms (and version) are you using - MySQL, SQL Server, etc... ?

Comment: Added MySQL tag based on error message in comments *"Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '( "*. Please update if that's incorrect.  Also we still need to know what version as version 8.x has very different functionality than 5.x

Comment: Thanks. MySQL is correct. I will need to verify on the version and will update with sample data and expected outcome as soon as I can.

Comment: @SOS I have updated my post. Due to the request of expected outcome (thanks for that, I should have thought of it) I realized I wasn't asking the full question as well. Hopefully the edits help clarify everything but if there is anything else that might help let me know.

Comment: Are the sample dates correct? Because it seems like all of the records have an  `event_timestamp >= '2022-04-04 00:00:00'`, meaning all clients have a *"..matching event occurring after the specified date"

Comment: The dates are correct. In theory if our dev team is keeping up each client should get one of these events a week. So all clients have an event that matches before the date and only clients `3` and `4` have gotten one after the date. I am looking to pull any clients that have not had the event occur after the date. I will edit my post again to be more clear on the wording. "inverse of the above" may not be explicit enough.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean by "inverse of the above". But I also think there's something missing from the requirements criteria, or maybe you just need to post different sample data ...? Because using the current sample, the "inverse" wouldn't return 1 and 2. It wouldn't return *anything at all*. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=80295b8bd72169af8c3bf2b4469740a2

Comment: Man, so sorry. When I pulled some data from the actual table I had to modify the dates and forgot to change the month. I will edit that now. Also, I think I found a potential solution but this is the most in depth I have gotten with SQL before so I'm not sure if it is a good/efficient solution or not.

Comment: Ahh okay. Knew there was something hinky with the data .... ;-) Thanks for updating it.

Comment: Totally. I modified the year and day already. That's the stupid part. lol

Comment: No worries, happens to us all. The NOT EXISTS looks good. Though no need for the GROUP BY there. Also, best to prefix all columns with the source alias for clarity.  dbfiddle.uk seems to be down, so here's another version https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f3e2fkyZF8wy8gRetZPFrG/0 . Anyway, glad you got it working ... and don't forget to post your solution as an "answer" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample data provided now does help (a lot) but it does not contain some columns that are referenced nor does it contain data that will present a result for the query you are seeking. So, I have added some columns and data and amended some data as well to suit.

```
INSERT INTO tools_clients(client_id,client_name,client_developer)
VALUES (1,'foo',12),
       (2,'fooBar',15),
       (3,'Bar',21),
       (4,'raBoof',37),
       (5,'2answer-or-not',67); --<< added

INSERT INTO tools_events(event_id,event_type,event_value,event_client,event_timestamp)
VALUES
 (23,'taskUpdated','needs approval (dev)',1,'2022-04-04 13:08:22'), -- date change
 (25,'taskUpdated','needs approval (dev)',2,'2022-04-04 14:22:07'), -- date change
 (28,'taskUpdated','needs approval (dev)',3,'2022-04-04 15:09:13'), -- date change
 (29,'taskUpdated','needs approval (dev)',4,'2022-04-04 15:36:17'), -- date change
 (32,'taskUpdated','needs approval (dev)',3,'2022-04-05 16:42:35'),
 (38,'taskUpdated','needs approval (dev)',4,'2022-04-05 19:01:25');

INSERT INTO tools_events(event_id,event_type,event_value,event_client,event_timestamp) 
VALUES (138,'not-taskUpdated','not-needs approval (dev)',4,'2022-04-05 19:01:25'); -- added
```

So we can run a query (based on original subquery in question):

```
SELECT
      t1.event_id
    , t1.event_user
    , t1.event_client
    , t1.event_timestamp
FROM tools_events AS t1
WHERE  (
        t1.event_type = 'taskUpdated'
        AND t1.event_value = 'needs approval (dev)'
        )
    AND t1.event_timestamp >= '2022-04-04 00:00:00'

+----------+------------+--------------+-----------------+
| event_id | event_user | event_client | event_timestamp |
+----------+------------+--------------+-----------------+
|       23 |            |            1 | 2022-04-04      |
|       25 |            |            2 | 2022-04-04      |
|       28 |            |            3 | 2022-04-04      |
|       29 |            |            4 | 2022-04-04      |
|       32 |            |            3 | 2022-04-05      |
|       38 |            |            4 | 2022-04-05      |
+----------+------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

and get the negative of that query by using `NOT (...)`:

```
SELECT
      t1.event_id
    , t1.event_user
    , t1.event_client
    , t1.event_timestamp
FROM tools_events AS t1
WHERE  NOT (
        t1.event_type = 'taskUpdated'
        AND t1.event_value = 'needs approval (dev)'
        )
    AND t1.event_timestamp >= '2022-04-04 00:00:00'

+----------+------------+--------------+-----------------+
| event_id | event_user | event_client | event_timestamp |
+----------+------------+--------------+-----------------+
|      138 |            |            4 | 2022-04-05      |
+----------+------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Note how `event_client` 4 exists in both those results, but there is no reference to `event_client` 5, this is important later

If you are looking for clients that have had an event that is `t1.event_type = 'taskUpdated' AND t1.event_value = 'needs approval (dev)'` **PLUS** an event that is `NOT(t1.event_type = 'taskUpdated' AND t1.event_value = 'needs approval (dev)'` then this will produce that result:

```
SELECT client_id, client_name, client_developer
FROM `tools_clients` AS clients
WHERE client_id IN (
    SELECT
          t1.event_client
    FROM tools_events AS t1
    WHERE  NOT (
            t1.event_type = 'taskUpdated'
            AND t1.event_value = 'needs approval (dev)'
            )
    AND t1.event_timestamp >= '2022-04-04 00:00:00')


+-----------+-------------+------------------+
| client_id | client_name | client_developer |
+-----------+-------------+------------------+
|         4 | raBoof      |               37 |
+-----------+-------------+------------------+
```

However if you only want clients that have absolutely no events that meet these criteria `t1.event_type = 'taskUpdated' AND t1.event_value = 'needs approval (dev)'`  then there are 2 options. Using a left join, here we join the rows to DO match the criteria, but then look for those records where the join produces NULL (this is therefore the "negative" of the criteria):

```
SELECT client_id, client_name, client_developer
FROM `tools_clients` AS clients
left join tools_events AS events ON clients.client_id = events.event_client
        AND events.event_type = 'taskUpdated'
        AND events.event_value = 'needs approval (dev)'
        AND events.event_timestamp >= '2022-04-04 00:00:00'
WHERE client_status > 0
  AND events.event_client IS NULL
```

or, a NOT EXISTS (*also known as a left semi-join*);

```
SELECT client_id, client_name, client_developer
FROM `tools_clients` AS clients
WHERE client_status > 0
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT NULL
      FROM tools_events AS events
      WHERE event_type = 'taskUpdated'
        AND event_value = 'needs approval (dev)'
        AND event_timestamp >= '2022-04-04 00:00:00'
        AND clients.client_id = events.event_client
      )
```

both of those queries result is:

```
+-----------+----------------+------------------+
| client_id |  client_name   | client_developer |
+-----------+----------------+------------------+
|         5 | 2answer-or-not |               67 |
+-----------+----------------+------------------+
```

Note when using `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` the select clause of the subquery does not have to "return" anything so you can use `select null` or `select 1` or `select *`. This is because `EXISTS` is just testing if the criteria of the from/where clause exist or not. Also, because that select clause does not really "return" anything, it is NOT necessary to use GROUP BY (or select distinct) in the `NOT EXISTS` subquery. It is also less efficient to include that GROUP BY in this form of subquery as it just wasted effort.

nb: This is very different to using IN() where the data IS "returned" by the select clause.

So hopefully you can see that there are various ways to negate your conditions - but how you negate them can produce different overall results. To see all of these queries running use: **db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0275f5d36997a394f5ee209358aba57f)**

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to negate a set of where clause predicates is to use `NOT(...)`

```
SELECT
      t1.event_id
    , t1.event_user
    , t1.event_client
    , t1.event_timestamp
FROM tools_events AS t1
WHERE NOT (
        t1.event_type = 'taskUpdated'
        AND t1.event_value = 'needs approval (dev)'
        )
    AND t1.event_timestamp >= '2022-04-04 00:00:00'
ORDER BY t1.event_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

and your existing query could be simplified too:

```
SELECT
      t1.event_id
    , t1.event_user
    , t1.event_client
    , t1.event_timestamp
FROM tools_events AS t1
WHERE t1.event_type = 'taskUpdated'
    AND t1.event_value = 'needs approval (dev)'
    AND t1.event_timestamp >= '2022-04-04 00:00:00'
ORDER BY t1.event_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

You do not specify which database or version, but if your db/version support window functions such as row_number() then you might be able to get both records in one query like this:

```
SELECT
      event_id
    , event_user
    , event_client
    , event_timestamp
FROM (
    SELECT 
          event_id
        , event_user
        , event_client
        , event_timestamp
        , row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CASE WHEN event_type = 'taskUpdated'
                    AND event_value = 'needs approval (dev)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            ORDER BY event_timestamp DESC
            ) AS rn
    FROM tools_events
    WHERE event_timestamp >= '2022-04-04 00:00:00'
    ) AS d
WHERE rn = 1
```

this divdes the data into 2 "partitions" and for each of those the row with the latest event timestamp will get a row number of 1. So both wanted rows are returned in one query.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I don't think the `NOT` did exactly what I was looking for. I think I might still need some sort of `JOIN` for that?

The simplified query ran great and was much faster but again, with the NOT it didn't quite work.

I did try the `row_number` example and got this:
`Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '( PARTITION BY CASE WHEN event_type = 'taskUpdated' ' at line 12` so I think I can use `row_number` but something is still not quite working right with that either.

Comment: What database type do you actually use? (eg: MySQL) and the version? (Eg. MySQL v5 does not support row_number but version 8 does). "Nb: SQL" is not enough to tell us what specific syntax is needed in our answers.

Comment: By the way, if we had sample data and your expected result using just that data, then we could  test approaches to your need. [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Apologies, and thanks for clarifying the need there. Totally makes sense but this is my first time needing assistance this complex I think so I've never needed to give such details before. In all of that, I realized I wasn't even fully asking the correct question so I clarified that as well that the final result will hopefully be a pull from the `tools_clients` table. Let me know if there is anything else I can give to help clarify the situation. Thanks!

Comment: I think you might have gotten me there with your modified version of my query. I edited my post accordingly. Let me know if that looks like a solid solution or not. If so, I would love to still give you credit as I would not have gotten there without your help but I know just accepting this answer as is will not help the community down the road. What is a normal process here? Should you add in the final piece and then I can accept it? Alternatively if there is a better approach and you wanted to edit your answer for that I will accept it.

Comment: I opted to add another answer incorporating the use of NOT EXISTS (and another solution). I feel this is less confusing than editing the original.